# Compare two columns and insert value to next column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have file which contains data in columnwise manner. Please help me to get desired output. I have tried to use awk but not able to insert the value.

```
- A  B  C   D   E
- 6 15  78  4   
- 4 14  77  4   23
- 5 13  79  2   45
- 5 16  81  4   
- 5 16  81  4   65
```

I need to check if column E is blank, then if column A=6 then insert 240 in column E and A=5 then insert 120 and A=4 then insert 0 in blank space.

Expected Output:

```
- A B   C   D   E
- 6 15 78   4   240
- 4 14 77   4   0
- 5 13 79   2   120
- 5 16 81   4   120
- 5 16 81   4   120
```

Comment: Seems to me you're modifying `E` in any case, regardless of if it's empty?

Comment: can we see what you tried? then we could lead you to the final answer (in a hopefully-understandable way)

Answer (score 2):

According to your expected output, the `E` field's emptiness does not make much influence.
It's enough to check `A` field value with following:

```
awk '{ if($2==6) $6=240; else if($2==5) $6=120; else if($2==4) $6=0 }1' file | column -t
```

The output:

```
-  A  B   C   D  E
-  6  15  78  4  240
-  4  14  77  4  0
-  5  13  79  2  120
-  5  16  81  4  120
-  5  16  81  4  120
```